# Lambda vs Kinesis iteratorAge - Difference?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis

What is the difference between the iteratorAge displayed in the montitoring for a Kinesis stream and the monitoring of a consuming lambda (using eventsourcemapping)?

I know the one in the stream is a combined view of all shard and consumers but is there any other difference? The metric on the stream is always at 0, but the lambda metric fluctuates a few hundred or thousand ms up and down. That seems to make more sense to me since it's using batch polling?

Shouldn't I see this up&down behaviour on the stream as well?
Seems like these metrics should be correlated?